How to run a trigger only for active tabs, but not for open tabs?
In the contentScript.tsx file I track storage changes, and if storage has changed, I show a specific component. But, when changing storage, this works for all tabs that are generally open, but I need to do it only for the active tab. How can this be implemented?
const App =() =>{
  const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() =>{
    chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((changes,area)=>{
      if(area==="local"&&changes.hasOwnProperty("isForbidden")){
        const newValue=changes["isForbidden"].newValue
        setError(newValue)
      }
    })
  },[])

  return(
    <>
      {error?
      <>
      <div>Ошибка</div> 
        </> 
        :null
      }
    </>
  )
}


Check document.hasFocus() or document.visibilityState === 'visible'
